# How to convert an integer to string multiple times using stringstream object?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I want to take an input as a integer and then concatenate it with a string. This will be for multiple times. The output will be the previous string with this new integer value.  After taking  input  of an integer number I used `stringstream` object for converting it. Then I concatenate it. But I’ve got expected output for the first time. But the next time when I take input from the user and try to concatenate it with the previous string output string in the concatenated part is the same of my first input integer. So how can I use this `stringstream` object for further use.

Here is my code:

```
string s = "Previous Choices :   ";
    int n;
    string d;
    stringstream ss;
    while(1) {
        cin>>n;
        ss << n;
        ss >> d;
        s += d;
        cout<<s<<”   ”<<endl;
}
```

**My inputs**

```
10
20
30
```

***My expected output is***

```
Previous Choices :   10
Previous Choices :   10 20
Previous Choices :   10 20 30
```

**But the output is coming like this:**

```
Previous Choices :   10
Previous Choices :   10 10
Previous Choices :   10 10 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your did not clear your stringstream object for further use. That is why it is containing the first input value and adding this for all of your inputs.

So to clear this object you just add the following this code

```
ss.clear();
```

Then your code will be like this

```
string s = "Previous Choices :   ";
    int n;
    string d;
    stringstream ss;
    while(1) {
        cin>>n;
        ss << n;
        ss >> d;
        s += d;
        cout<<s<<”   ”<<endl;
        ss.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string s = "Previous Choices : ";
    int n;
    stringstream ss;
    while(1) 
    {
        cin >> n;
        ss << n;
        //cout << "in ss stream is: " << ss.str() << endl;
        s = s + ss.str() + " ";
        cout << s << endl;
        ss.str(string());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works as You expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it much more simply, without the intermediates `s` and `d`, directly using the stream as your accumulator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "Previous Choices : ";
    while(1) 
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        ss << n;
        cout << ss.str() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```